# SSIS job is not able to access the Azure File share path

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, sql-server-agent, azure-files

I am testing the azure file share with SSIS hosted on Azure VM. However, I am facing an issue while running the job.

- Package execution through Visual Studio is successful
- Package execution through catalog also is successful

Package execution through the Job is FAILING with the error The File Name "\.windows.net<FolderName>\file.csv" specified in the connection was not valid

I tried running the job with the proxy account having access to the Azure share folder (Same account used to run the package), however it failed with the same error.

Both UNC and as a mapped drive was tested.

Any suggestion or advice on this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving read/write permissions *(For the Azure share folder)* to the SQL Database Engine Service account `NT SERVICE\MSSQL$<Instance Name>` and `NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT` *(Where `<Instance Name>` should be replaced by the installed instance name)*:

- [Configure File System Permissions for Database Engine Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-file-system-permissions-for-database-engine-access?view=sql-server-2017)

Also, feel free to read more about SQL Server service accounts in the following documentation:

- [Configure Windows Service Accounts and Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-windows-service-accounts-and-permissions?view=sql-server-ver15)